# Sending blob files to server

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to send a audio recording to server and save it as .wav. I am using angular on the front end and .net core on server. I was able to record, then make a blob of type "audio/wav". For sending it to server, I convert it into an array buffer and then the array buffer to base64 string which I post to controller.

On the server side when I write those bytes(after extracting array buffer from base 64), to a wav file, I cant play it. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong on the .net controller side.

If someone knows a cleaner way of doing this, please let me know

Comment: Please confirm whether its `angular` or `angularjs`. Your tag and question contradicts each other. Also, please share the code which you have worked upon till now.

Comment: May be your content type not correct when extracting

Comment: I am not using content type while extracting. simply saving the byte array as wav

Comment: what's the first, say 80 bytes of the upload payload

Comment: Two things: 1) If you bind server-side to a `byte[]` ASP.NET Core will take care of converting your base64 string to a `byte[]` for you (assuming you're posing JSON here, which seems likely. 2) Your issue is likely the "make a blob of type audio/wav" part. How are you doing that?

Comment: @ChrisPratt here is the code
`this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
          const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to create an array buffer. Just use a file-input and send form-data.

Assuming you are on angular 4.3++ and using [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) from `@angular/common/http`:

The angular-service method

```
public uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.Append('myFile', file);
   return this.http.post('my-api-url', formData);
}
```

now you asp.net-core endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
 // attention name of formfile must be equal to the key u have used for formdata    
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromForm] IFormFile myFile)
{
     var totalSize = myFile.Length;
     var fileBytes = new byte[myFile.Length];

     using (var fileStream = myFile.OpenReadStream())
     {
         var offset = 0;

         while (offset < myFile.Length)
         {
             var chunkSize = totalSize - offset < 8192 ? (int) totalSize - offset : 8192;

             offset += await fileStream.ReadAsync(fileBytes, offset, chunkSize);
         }
     }
   // now save the file on the filesystem
   StoreFileBytes("mypath", fileBytes);
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution for passing a blob to Asp.net core. I tried using ArrayBuffer then converting it to UInt8Array and then finally converting it to Base64 encoded string. Then I converted it back to byte array on Asp.Net Core, but When i tried to create a file using the bytes created, I got an empty pdf. 
With form data it works perfectly. Thanks a lot...

Comment: this pair of procedures without any extraneous noise around them are exactly what I needed (and have been hard to find)