# BAD Reuqest Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFileCollection

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am receiving Bad request when uploading my file and converting it into json and passing to my .net core webapi controller.

here its an error screenshot.i have also console the model as well.

[image]

here its my code in typescript

```js
        const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        var approval = {
          ...this.MemberApproval,
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(approval));
        return this.http.post(this.Url + '/Member/UpdateMember/update',   JSON.stringify(approval), { headers: httpHeaders });
```

on .net core webapi i am doing like this.

My model :

```cs
      public class MemberApproval
        {
            public string Notes;
            public IFormCollection Attachment;
            public int ApprovalStatus;
            public int SubsId;
            public int MemberId;
        }
```

My controller :

```cs
         [Route("[action]/{item}")]
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult UpdateMember([FromBody]MemberApproval approval )
            {


                if (approval !=null)
                {
                    _repo.UpdateMemberStatus(approval);

                }

                return Ok();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending blob files to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032438/sending-blob-files-to-server)

Comment: Marked it as possible duplicate. Kinda the same question has been asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032438/sending-blob-files-to-server and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424712/fromform-with-iformfile-using-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit a file to ASP.Net Core you have to use FromForm and IFormFile like this

```cs
[HttpPost("SavePost")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SavePost([FromForm]PostViewModel viewModel)
{
    var postOptionsViewModel = _jsonParsePostOptionDefaultVm.ToObject(viewModel.PostOptionsViewModel);
    viewModel.PostOptionsDefaultViewModel = postOptionsViewModel;

    if (viewModel.Id.HasValue)
    {
        await _postRepository.EditPost(viewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        await _postRepository.SavePost(viewModel);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

My model will have property List so you can submit multi file to server

```cs
public List<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
```

My FE side code will be like this. I'm using react but mostly not different in the way we submit a formdata to server

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Title", this.state.title);
formdata.append("File", this.state.File);
```

Remember to set Content-Type header to 'multipart/form-data'