# how to use FormData for put request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, multipartform-data, put

I was trying to upload files on server using *angular reactive form*.When i try to edit form that generate an error *internal server error* but when **i use postman it updates file successfully** 
i don`t know what i am missing in my **FormData put request**? post request works successfully

***addteacher.component.html***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators ,FormGroup,FormArray,FormControl} from '@angular/forms'
import { TeacherServiceService } from '../shared/teacher/teacher-service.service';
import {ActivatedRoute,Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Teacher} from '../shared/teacher/teacher';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-addteacher',
  templateUrl: './addteacher.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addteacher.component.css']
})
export class AddteacherComponent implements OnInit {
  teacherform:FormGroup;
  teacher: Teacher;
  FormTitle:String;





  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private teacherService: TeacherServiceService,
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private router : Router

    ) { }



  ngOnInit() {

    this.teacherform = this.fb.group({
      t_p_img: [''],
      t_id: [''],
      t_name: [''],
      t_desig: [''],
      t_dob: [''],
      t_pswd: [''],
      t_email: ['',[Validators.required]],
      t_gender: [''],
      t_phone: [''],
      t_quali: [''],
      t_address: ['']
       });


//Getting Teacher id
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
      const techId = params.get('id');
      if(techId){
        this.FormTitle = "Update Teacher Form";

       this.getTeacherr(techId);
      }
      else{
        this.FormTitle = "Teacher Registration Form";
        this.teacher = {
          t_id:null,
          t_name:'',
          t_desig: '',
          t_dob:null,
          t_email:'',
          t_pswd:'',
          t_gender:'',
          t_phone:null,
          t_quali:'',
          t_p_img:'',
          t_address:'',
          _id:null,
          courses:[]
        }
      }
    });

  }//
  selectedFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.teacherform.get('t_p_img').setValue(file);
    }
  }


  saveRecord():void {
    var formData:any = new FormData();
    var t_p_image = this.teacherform.value.t_p_img;
    var t_email = this.teacherform.value.t_email;
    var t_id = this.teacherform.value.t_id;
    var t_name = this.teacherform.value.t_name;
    var t_desig = this.teacherform.value.t_desig;
    var t_dob = this.teacherform.value.t_dob;
    var t_pswd = this.teacherform.value.t_pswd;
    var t_gender = this.teacherform.value.t_gender;
    var t_phone = this.teacherform.value.t_phone;
    var  t_quali = this.teacherform.value.t_quali;
    var  t_address= this.teacherform.value.t_address
    formData.append('file',t_p_image) ;
    formData.append('t_id',t_id) ;
    formData.append('t_name',t_name);
    formData.append('t_desig',t_desig);
    formData.append('t_dob',t_dob);
    formData.append('t_pswd',t_pswd);
    formData.append('t_email',t_email);
    formData.append('t_gender',t_gender);
    formData.append('t_phone',t_phone);
    formData.append('t_quali',t_quali);
    formData.append('t_address',t_address);



    // console.log(formData)


    //  this.MapFormValuesToTeacherModel();

    if(this.teacher._id){

    this.teacherService.updateTeacher(this.teacher._id,formData).subscribe(
      ()=>this.router.navigate(['teacher']),
      (err:any)=>console.log(err)


    );
  }else{

    this.teacherService.createTeacher(formData).subscribe(
      ()=>this.router.navigate(['teacher']),
      (err:any)=>console.log(err)

    );}
     }


  getTeacherr(techId:any){
    this.teacherService.getTeacher(techId).subscribe(
      (teacher:Teacher)=>{
        this.editTeacher(teacher);
        this.teacher = teacher
       } ,
      (err:any)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }

    )

  }



editTeacher(teacher:Teacher){
 this.teacherform.patchValue({
    t_p_img:teacher.t_p_img,
     t_id: teacher.t_id,
    t_name: teacher.t_name,
    t_desig: teacher.t_desig,
    t_dob: teacher.t_dob,
    t_pswd: teacher.t_pswd,
    t_email: teacher.t_email,
    t_gender: teacher.t_gender,
    t_phone: teacher.t_phone,
    t_quali: teacher.t_quali,
    t_address: teacher.t_address
    });
}


}
```

***This is TeacherServiceService***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Teacher} from './teacher';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable,throwError, from} from 'rxjs';
import {retry,catchError} from'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeacherServiceService {

  // Headers
  httpOptions={ 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type':'application/json'
    })
  }
  //Api Address
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  // Requests

  createTeacher(teacher:any) {

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/teacher',teacher)
     .pipe(
       retry(2),
       catchError(this.handleError)
     )};
   //Getting All the teacher
   showTeachers(): Observable <Teacher[]> {

    return this.http.get<Teacher[]>(this.apiUrl+'/teacher',)
     .pipe(
       retry(2),
       catchError(this.handleError)
     ) 

   };
  // get a Single Teacher
  getTeacher(id:any): Observable <Teacher>{
    return this.http.get<Teacher>(this.apiUrl + '/teacher/'+id, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )};

    // Updating Teacher
    updateTeacher(id,formData:any) {
      return this.http.put(this.apiUrl + '/teacher/'+id, formData)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
      };
```

***working with Postman Put request***
[image: This is Put Request Working image]

***Not working with formData Put request***
[image: Not Working when edit/put request]

Comment: can u share the curl command of postman & the screenshot of the error that you are getting

Comment: @ShashankVivek i did attached please check

Comment: @SAADA82 Try to open chrome network tab and check the outgoing PUT request to see the request body to know what happens

Comment: i did check i am unable to understand whats wrong

Comment: @SAADA82 : There seems to be something which is not detectable from the provided code. With `500` error code, your response is getting to server and the server is throwing error. Can you check the form Data on server side once and see of all values are passed correctly from client side

Comment: if there is any error on server side it should also not work using postman? is that

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set value property with file which is not correct and It'll throw error ,

```
this.teacherform.get('t_p_img').setValue(file);
```

Check this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361203/7122286

Comment: i did check your solution. problem is different here when i create new user with  file also works fine but when i edit user that throws error

Comment: please check now i did

Answer (score 1):

ok you can do it like this

**First:**

```
slectedFile: File;
//imgUrl for showing it in html tag
imgUrl = '../assets/img/profilepic.png';
```

**Second:**

```
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
   //........
   file: [null]
});
```

**Third:**

```
onFileSelect(file) {
    if (file.target.files[0]) {
      this.slectedFile = file.target.files[0] as File;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.slectedFile);
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        this.imgUrl = event.target.result;
      };
   }
}
```

**And Last:**

> which I assume your main problem is here

```
  const data= new FormData();
  if (this.slectedFile) {
    data.append('file', this.slectedFile, this.slectedFile.name);
  }
```

and I should mention that personally use this package for input

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-file-input

and in the html side you just say :

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-12 ml-10 ngxmatfileinput">
    <ngx-mat-file-input
    (change)="onFileSelect($event)"
    formControlName="file"
    accept="image/*">
    </ngx-mat-file-input>
    <img [src]="imgUrl" class="float-left icon-fileupload" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for  explanation.
 When i register first time it works fine but when i edit it does not work ?

Comment: what do you mean by edit? reselect the image you mean?

Comment: Edit Complete form, i mean put request

Comment: please have a look i have update question with screen shots

Comment: change the content type to 'Content-Type': multipart/form-data and try again OR 'Content-Type': undefined or delete it completely

Comment: i don`t know what the problem is ? if i create new teacher with image file it creates successfully  using FormData but when i edit existing teacher that does not work ? with put request

Comment: check your network tab and be aware that postman dos did not send a preflight request like what browser do, thats why its working

Comment: i did check i am unable to understand 

i request headers from postman

`Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.21.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a2a11795-b03e-4929-9534-75d8904b6c97
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------791395300432928507817109
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 346796
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: from  angular App

`GET /login/edit/5e06e9e79aeb85214415efcc HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:4200

Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9