# How to upload image with other form control (Angular 8) and asp.net core api

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

```
        I want fill form which have upload profile image and other controls like Name,address 
        I am using angular 8 for client side and asp.net core for backend..
        I want viewmodel which contains all properties.
```

I have used angular8 for uploading image in formdata.I have gone through https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/.My main question is how to receive uploaded file in ViewModel not in httpRequest.Form.Files["ImageFile"]

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public IActionResult CreateApplication(ApplicationModel model)
 {
         //want to capture uploaded image 
            return Ok();
  }
```

Comment: `main question is how to receive uploaded file in ViewModel` You can refer to this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349595/how-to-upload-file-from-angular-to-asp-net-core-web-api/59352751#59352751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this tutorial, can be very helpful: [Click](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/)

Here is way how i`d do it:

```
[HttpPost]       
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBodyType([FromForm]ApplicationModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Images");
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                    var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                        await stream.FlushAsync();
                    }

                    model.ImagePath = dbPath;
                    await _context.Add(model);

                    return Ok();
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have model which contains collection of model .For example public class 
  public class ApplicationModel{
  public ApplicationDetails applicationDetails{get;set;}
  public ApplicationDetails applicationDetails{get;set;}
}
How [FromFile] works

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, the problem was that the directory names were not fixed, they were created by the newly created Id of the product, so the solution was to carry out a check for the directory and if it's not there, create it.

For example

```
if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
}
```

Once it's created with the new Id it can be used/found.