# Why are my files not saving to my specified directory in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save files to a local directory in my ASp.NET Core application, whilst there are other, better ways to do this, this is the way that's being requested by the user.  So, I set up my file upload in my controller as below:

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CreateProductViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model !=null)
    {
        try
        {
            //Save the Product
            var product = new Products
            {
                Id = model.Products.Id,
                Title = model.Products.Title,
            };
            //Insert the product and get the newly created Id
            _productsService.InsertProduct(product);
            int newId = product.Id;

            //Process the Images
            if (model.Products.ProductImages != null)
            {
                try
                {                            
                    var root = _env.WebRootPath;
                    var images = model.Products.ProductImages;
                    var path = Path.Combine(root, "images", "products", newId.ToString());                            

                    foreach (var item in images) 
                    {
                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                        {                                    
                            Stream inStream = item.OpenReadStream();
                            using Image image = Image.Load(inStream);
                            int width = 350;
                            int height = 0;
                            var clone = image.Clone(i => i.Resize(width, height));
                            clone.SaveAsJpeg(stream);                                
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        };
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
}
```

Here is the model that represents this data

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Products : BaseEntity
    {           
        public string Title { get; set; }  

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFileCollection ProductImages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There are a few things going on, the process needs to be as follows

- Product is created
- Newly created product id is grabbed
- Image path is created using the new Product Id
- All images are iterated over, processed, and saved to that new directory.

i.e.

- `wwwroot/images/products/54/imagefile01.jpg`
- `wwwroot/images/products/54/imagefile02.jpg`
- `wwwroot/images/products/54/imagefile03.jpg`

However, it's not quite working like that.  The images are not being saved, the application is creating an empty file (0 bytes) with the product id as the name:

- `wwwroot/images/products/54`

What am I doing wrong that it's not created the Product Id correctly and why isn't it saving my files into that directory? I feel I've missed a step.

Comment: _int height = 0;_ is that correct?

Comment: You declare a wrong path. See how i do it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321069/how-to-upload-image-with-other-form-control-angular-8-and-asp-net-core-api/61321916#61321916) , maybe you will find something helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link @Mateech but I get the same error as I've mentioned below with your solution too.  `Could not find a part of the file path` with the full path being: `{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\GitRepos\\MyProject\\MyProject\\wwwroot\\images\\products\\37\\somefile1.jpg'."}`

Answer (score 0):

The `path` is wrong. You are saving all of the iamges to the same directory as same name. Because of the line `using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path))`

And image height is 0. You have to change that too.

Try this.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CreateProductViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model !=null)
    {
        try
        {
            //Save the Product
            var product = new Products
            {
                Id = model.Products.Id,
                Title = model.Products.Title,
            };
            //Insert the product and get the newly created Id
            _productsService.InsertProduct(product);
            int newId = product.Id;

            //Process the Images
            if (model.Products.ProductImages != null)
            {
                try
                {                            
                    var root = _env.WebRootPath;
                    var images = model.Products.ProductImages;
                    var saveDirectory = Path.Combine(root, "images", "products", newId.ToString());                            

                    var iterator = 0;
                    foreach (var item in images) 
                    {
                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(saveDirectory, $"image{iterator++}.jpg")))
                        {                                    
                            Stream inStream = item.OpenReadStream();
                            using Image image = Image.Load(inStream);
                            int width = 350;
                            int height = WHY TIS IS ZERO?;
                            var clone = image.Clone(i => i.Resize(width, height));
                            clone.SaveAsJpeg(stream);                                
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        };
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, when I upload an image using the above approach I get an erro in my catch of  `Could not find a part of the file path` with the full path being: `{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\GitRepos\\MyProject\\MyProject\\wwwroot\\images\\products\\37\\somefile1.jpg'."}`

Comment: The use of `height=0` is specific to `SixLabors.ImageSharp` for processing the image, when the height is define as `0` maintains the aspect ratio for whatever width you specify.

Comment: The saveDirectory must exists. Use Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDirectory) after the line 'var saveDirectory....'

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly read the folder that has not been created, and you don't need to create the same file path every time.

Before creating, please add the judgment of whether the file path exists.

And you don't need to convert the jpg in the created path to Stream format to store the uploaded image. You can directly use the `clone.Save(filePath)` method to save these images in the form of jpeg.

Please try the following code.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(ProductModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Save the Product
                    var product = new NewProducts
                    {
                        Id = model.Products.Id,
                        Title = model.Products.Title,
                    };
                    //Insert the product and get the newly created Id
                     _productsService.InsertProduct(product);
                    int newId = product.Id;

                    //Process the Images
                    if (model.Products.ProductImages != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var root = _env.WebRootPath;
                            var images = model.Products.ProductImages;
                            var path = Path.Combine(root, "images", "products", newId.ToString());
                            var iterator = 0;
                            foreach (var item in images)
                            {
                                var filePath = Path.Combine(path, $"imagefile0{iterator++}.jpg");
                                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                                } 
                                Stream inStream = item.OpenReadStream();
                                using Image image = Image.Load(inStream);
                                int width = 350;
                                int height = 0;
                                var clone = image.Clone(i => i.Resize(width, height));
                                clone.Save(filePath); 
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                };
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        }
```

Here is the debug process and result:

[image]