# Unable to add SharePoint list item with attachment from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API using NgModel

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, sharepoint, attachment

I have added the SharePoint list item with an attachment from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API. I have used FormControl in the Angular application.

I have referred below link,
[How to Upload File from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349595/how-to-upload-file-from-angular-to-asp-net-core-web-api)

Now, I need to perform the same using NgModel instead of FormControl in the Angular application.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use example of this link, [How to Upload File from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349595/how-to-upload-file-from-angular-to-asp-net-core-web-api). i think must be like this :

**html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
        <label for="Name">
            Blog Name
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" [(ngModel)]="Name">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="TileImage">
            Tile Image
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="TileImage" [(ngModel)]="TileImage">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Create Blog</button>

</form>
```

**typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BlogService } from '../blog-services/blog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-blog',
  templateUrl: './new-blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-blog.component.css']
})
export class NewBlogComponent implements OnInit {
  public Name = '';
  public TileImage= '';
  constructor(private blogService: BlogService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.blogService.postBlog({Name:this.Name,TileImage:this.TileImage});
    this.Name='';
    this.TileImage='';
  }

}
```