# Upload file from angular to asp.net core web api controller

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, types

[How to Upload File from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349595/how-to-upload-file-from-angular-to-asp-net-core-web-api)

I wanted to know how to write it's controller part can anyone help me in that?

What to right inside controller

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload File from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349595/how-to-upload-file-from-angular-to-asp-net-core-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

Angular simple example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-montalcini-49h53n?file=/src/app/app.component.html
**Look App Folder**

Web Api Controller:
Object Rq:

```
public class UploadFileRq
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPut("yourUrl")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] UploadFileRq file)
        {
            // your process here
            return Ok();
        }
```